# Rounding numbers with R

Tags: r, math

I would like to round numbers to the first integer according to a definite spacing, i.e.

```
if the spacing is s=5

6.5 -> 5
8.5 -> 10
```

with the possibility to change the spacing s. I can do that with round but just with 10,100,etc..

Many thanks

Comment: `round(6.5 / 5,0) * 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plyr` has a built-in that does this with fancy settings (`round_any`)

```
require(plyr)
round_any(102.1, 10)               
round_any(99.01, 5, f = ceiling)  
round_any(1.1, 5, f = ceiling)  
round_any(6, 5, f = floor)   
round_any(6.3, 0.25, f = floor)
```